# Installing error for jasmine

Tags: node.js, jasmine, package.json

I am trying to install jasmine in my node project folder but it is ended up with some errors and i am not aware of it,can anyone suggest me some help....

```
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN prefer global jasmine-node@1.14.5 should be installed with -g
npm WARN unmet dependency /var/www/html/meanjs/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt requires request@'~2.74.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /var/www/html/meanjs/node_modules/request,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.75.0
npm WARN unmet dependency /var/www/html/meanjs/node_modules/protractor requires jasmine@'2.4.1' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /var/www/html/meanjs/node_modules/jasmine,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.5.2
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-38-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "jasmine-node" "--save"
npm ERR! node v4.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package grunt@1.0.1 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-cssmin@0.12.3 wants grunt@>=0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-mocha-istanbul@5.0.2 wants grunt@>=0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-ng-annotate@2.0.2 wants grunt@>=0.4.5
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-nodemon@0.4.2 wants grunt@>=0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-sass@1.2.1 wants grunt@>=0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-connect@0.11.2 wants grunt@>=0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-csslint@0.4.0 wants grunt@>=0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-karma@0.12.2 wants grunt@>=0.4.x
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-protractor-runner@3.2.0 wants grunt@>=0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-istanbul@0.6.2 wants grunt@~0.4.5

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/www/html/meanjs/modules/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Just install a newer grunt version.  Make sure you follow the grunt project set up instructions very carefully.

Comment: i tried installing new grunt with the command npm install grunt-version --save-dev  ,but same error remains...........

Comment: Ok, you may need to spend some time working on English skills.  Its either that or try Adderall -- not sure.